# Firebase Cloud Functions: save TypeScript Map() - how?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a Firebase Cloud Functions written in TypeScript that is supposed to save an instance Map() to Cloud Firestore. (The key of the map is a user ID and the value is an object with 2 simple attributes; due to the nature of the keys, I can't know them before runtime.)
When trying to save the map object directly, I get:

> Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object (found in field "member_details")

Another approach was to avoid using a Map() object and initialize it with {} - like this:

```
  let memberDetailsMap = {};
  this.memberDetails.forEach(md => {
    let payload = {
      "name": md.name,
      "age": md.age,
    }
    memberDetailsMap[md.uid] = payload; // <- !!!!!!!! ERROR
  })
```

This even prevents me from compiling the TS to JS with the message:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

One more thing I tried is to use *JSON.stringify(memberDetailsMap)* - but this resulted in an empty object.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to work around this issue. Do you have some hint/solution for that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to show more context, such as how you assign `this.memberDetails`.  What you have now isn't enough to get a grasp of what all is going on in your code. There is is probably a much more idiomatic way of creating `this.memberDetailsMap` than iterating `this.memberDetails` with `forEach`.

Comment: this.memberDetails is (was) an Array of MemberDetail objects. But indeed I now changed it into a map/object. If I used Map() for memberDetails, what would be an idiomatic way to get an object of the type described by pakash out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this issue by setting the type for `memberDetailsMap` explicitly like:

```
let memberDetailsMap: { [key: string]: any} = {};
```

Comment: `new Map<string, any>()` not recognized as Firestore document btw. This one works `{[key: string]: unknown}`